# nginx - codeigniter gives white screen

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, php

I am creating a web app using nginx and codeigniter, but when install codeigniter project it give white screen

**Checks**

1) nginx is installed because it shows default page which says "Welcome",
2) phpfpm is installed because a file which shows phpinfo(); is worked perfectly,

But when i have installed the codeigniter project it shows blank screen or white screen.

nginx default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /srv/www/vishalnlabz.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 104.131.57.74;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            if ($uri !~ "^/images/") {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            }
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/vishalnlabz.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on notices and errors in your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```